# Is it possible to hide an app from App Store search results?

Tags: ios-appstore

We'd like to launch an iPhone app on an invitation-only basis to begin with. We'd like invited people to be able to find the app in the App Store via an email link, but not have other people be able to find it easily. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible with the App Store as apps released there are available for everyone.

You can use Apple's [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) beta distribution with the [<sub>[image]</sub> TestFlight](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/testflight/id899247664?mt=8&at=1001lwpF) app to distribute a version of your app to invited people.